# Mobile friendly photo upload / crop

Tags: filepicker.io

We're using filepicker for users to choose a profile photo. We need to crop the photo to a square. We had been doing this automatically, but now want to allow users to choose the crop region.

We tried using jCrop as you do on your homepage but didn't work well on mobile. Can you point us to any canonical examples of pick and crop and store, that work well on mobile?

Answer (score 0):

Mobile cropping gets a bit tricky, as many don't have good support for the touchmove events, or render without using WebGL and therefore are not very responsive. Aviary (http://www.aviary.com/) may be your best best.